# Firebase storage security

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I am new to Firebase and trying to develop an Ionic2 app using Firebase + Firebase storage using AngularFire2.

I have few PDF on storage & there URL in Firebase database.

I have an authenticated user on app through Firebase auth.

Now when a user downloads the file on his/her mobile, the system will get the downloadUrl, and a smart user can view it see it through NeoLoad or any other tool. then he can just share that direct file URL with anyone and download that pdf without the app.

1- I want to know if it is possible to restrict the file access from app only so that even if he has to file url, he cant download it.

2- Is it possible to generate dynamic URL that expires after some time or user-specific file URL only?

Answer (score 0):

***UPDATE***

Looking at this problem some more it looks like Firebase supports signed URLs. You can use them to limit the amount of time that URL can be used to access your files. Since you only want them used the app they can expire rather quickly. You can read about them here:

[Creating Signed URLs with a Program](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/create-signed-urls-program)

> This page describes how to programmatically create signed URLs, which are a mechanism for query string authentication for buckets and objects. Signed URLs are one way to control access to buckets and objects. A signed URL is associated with a bucket or object and gives time-limited read or write access to that specific resource. Anyone in possession of the URL has the access granted by the URL, regardless of whether they have a Google account.
>
> To learn more about Signed URLs, read the Overview of Signed URLs. To
>   learn how to create signed URLs quickly using gsutil, read Creating
>   Signed URLs with gsutil.

[Signed URLs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls)

> This page provides an overview of Signed URLs, which is a mechanism for query string authentication for buckets and objects. Signed URLs provide a way to give time-limited read or write access to anyone in possession of the URL, regardless of whether they have a Google account. To learn how to create a Signed URL, read Creating Signed URLs with gsutil and Creating Signed URLs with a Program. To learn about other ways of controlling access to buckets and objects, read Overview of Access Control.

Based on the documentation 
[Get Started with Storage Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/start)
[Understand Firebase Security Rules for Cloud Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/secure-files) and [Learn to Secure Files](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/secure-files)

You can set security rules for Firebase storage just like the database rules. This should prevent a user who has not been authenticated from accessing your files.

Hope this helps

Comment: How to use firebase GS download URL with angularfire because https download URL are not private